# Persistent op-amp oscillations only with oscilloscope

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-speed, oscillation

I'm currently debugging a high-speed amplifier circuit that seems to oscillate every time I connect an oscilloscope probe to it.  Below is a schematic:
[image: A schematic of a high speed amplifier circuit]

I started by populating the circuit up to the voltage divider between the two op-amps.  In this for, it oscillated when an oscilloscope probe was touched to the indicated spot. However, it behaved exactly as expected when the probe was fixed to a 1k resistor, and the other side of the resistor was touched to the same point.

I next populated the second half of the circuit, which oscillates whether the oscilloscope is connected through a 1k resistor, or directly to the output.  I ultimately intend to use this circuit to drive a several meter BNC cable, so it needs to be able to tolerate a decent capacitance on the output.  Presumably, the oscillations are only happening with the probe connected, because the current draw increases by more than a factor of 2, from ~3mA from each power line to ~7mA, when the oscilloscope probe is connected.  Although the frequency tends to vary quite a bit depending on the exact way the probe is connected, it teds to fall into the 30-70MHz range.

The layout of the circuit is shown below.  The PCB contains several extra footprints to allow for some design variations.  There are cutouts in the ground plane (blue) under the feedback loops to lower the parasitic capacitance.
[image: A picture of a PCB layout.]

One worrying thing I've noticed is that the power supply lines show quite a bit of oscillation when the op-amps are going crazy.  When nothing is connected to the output, the power lines are very quiet, but with +/-5V oscillations on the output, they exhibit about +/- 1V ripple.  Is this because of insufficient decoupling, or is it to be expected when op-amps are oscillating out of control?

I also tried raising the gain of the second stage to claw back some phase margin, changing the gain to about 3.8, and then to about 11.  Neither change seemed to cure the oscillations.

What are some steps I could take to track down exactly what my issue is?
Is my layout fundamentally flawed?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your layout certainly isn't *great* but it might be a circuit issue. Does it still happen if you replace the ferrites with shorts? I've had problems in the past with the inductance of power supply ferrites.

Comment: It's possible the OPA847 just doesn't like that much capacitive load, even if it's after a 10 Ω resistor. What model oscilloscope probe are you using? Is it 1x or 10x (or something else)?

Comment: Why don't you post the schematic used to generate the netlist for the PCB?

Comment: A @Heath mentioned a scope probe can cause oscillation because of its capacitance - especially if it is a x1 probe that can present >100pF load. This is beyond the level that which many opamps are stable.

Comment: The inductance of the scope ground loop and the scope capacitance often cause ringing or oscillations. There is usually a spring ground attachment that comes with the probe for this purpose that may help.